# Flutter: Android - How to open camera

Tags: android, flutter, camera, package, android-camera

I am trying to open the camera app on Android in Flutter. I don't want to open a camera in the app itself, I want to open the 'Camera' app as an external app.

My idea was to open it throught the 'external_app_launcher' package, but is there a unique package name for the camera on Android or how am I able to get the package name of the camera app?

Comment: Did you got your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I personally have never used this package, but it is mentioned on the official site of Flutter ([here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera)). So you should take a look at it:

[camera | Flutter Package](https://pub.dev/packages/camera)